# want to insert current time by default in datetime column with inserted date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I want to insert the current time automatically with the inserted date in datetime column. by default it inserts 00:00:00

I created the trigger

```
Create trigger tr_tm on emp
after insert,update
as
declare @tme time

set @tme=(select CONVERT(varchar(7),start_date,108) from emp)

update emp
set @tme=convert(varchar(8),getdate(),108)
where @tme='00:00:00'
go
```

but it shows error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_te, Line 15 Subquery returned
>   more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,
>   !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. The
>   statement has been terminated.

how it is possible??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This is SQL server, so why is it tagged MySQL?

Comment: add default contstraint with value `GETDATE()`

Comment: Single most common error with SQL Server triggers is to assume that `inserted` and `deleted` only contain one row. Second most common - not *using* the `inserted` and `deleted` tables, which tell you *specifically* which row(s) have just been affected.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add a [default constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187872.aspx) to your column.  The default constraint will be used to populate the column, when you do not provide a value.

**Example**

```
-- Example table.
CREATE TABLE Example
    (
        A   INT,
        B   TIME            DEFAULT(CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME))
    )
;
```

When inserting data the default will be applied, if we don't supply a value.

```
-- Adding data, without referencing column.
INSERT INTO Example
    (
        A
    )
VALUES
    (1),
    (2),
    (3)
;
```

You can also explicitly specify that you want the default value to be applied.

```
-- Adding data, using DEFAULT.
INSERT INTO Example
    (
        A,
        B
    )
VALUES
    (10, DEFAULT),
    (20, DEFAULT),
    (30, DEFAULT)       
;
```

You also retain the option of ignoring the default and supplying your own value.

```
-- Adding data without using default value.
INSERT INTO Example
    (
        A,
        B
    )
VALUES
    (100, '09:30:00'),
    (200, '10:30:00'),
    (300, '11:30:00')       
;
```

The three queries above returned:

```
A   B
1   13:19:28.1900000
2   13:19:28.1900000
3   13:19:28.1900000
10  13:19:28.1900000
20  13:19:28.1900000
30  13:19:28.1900000
100 09:30:00.0000000
200 10:30:00.0000000
300 11:30:00.0000000
```